# How can I use variable in a PowerShell command on Mac?

Tags: powershell

I installed PowerShell in Ubuntu and I am able to use it by typing `pwsh`. And I need to run a script to save a value in an variable in PowerShell like below code:

```
pwsh -Command $password=ConvertTo-SecureString 'MYPASSWORD' -AsPlainText -Force
```

I get an error

> =ConvertTo-SecureString: not found

from above command. It works fine if I remove the password variable

```
pwsh -Command ConvertTo-SecureString 'MYPASSWORD' -AsPlainText -Force
```

How can I save the command output to a variable in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably running that commandline from bash, so you need to prevent bash from expanding that variable when it evaluates the statement. Either escape the `$`:

```
pwsh -Command \$password=ConvertTo-SecureString 'MYPASSWORD' -AsPlainText -Force
```

or put the statement in single quotes:

```
pwsh -Command '$password=ConvertTo-SecureString "MYPASSWORD" -AsPlainText -Force'
```